# Getting an object of a private class in java

Tags: java

I am not so proficient in java, and have a small question.

A lot of times I see the following code:

```
public class A
{
   private class B {

       B() {
       }

       get() {
       return this;
       }
   }

   public B getB() {
      return new B().get();
   }    
}
```

My question is, what is the difference if getB() just returns new B() instead of new B.get()
Is it just good software engineering when you do return B().get(), or is there some deeper reasoning?

Comment: Don't forget the return type. Also method chaining.

Comment: In your current code, it's doing nothing. `return new B();` is equivalent.

Comment: In some cases, this might be used to ensure B is immutable. Really hard to be sure without looking at the real code, though.

Comment: If get() had `//do something` before `return this;`, I think you can see how it would make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

The `return this` returns current instance of `B`. In your case `new B().get();` returns new instance of `B` (created right now).

So `return new B().get();` and `new B()` do the same and equivalent.

The `get()` method or I would say `getInstance()` method we can use in Singleton pattern, like:

```
public class B {

 private static B instance = null; 

  public static B getInstance(){
   if(instance == null){
       instance = new B();
    }

    return instance;
  }    
}
```

So no matter how many times we call `getInstance()`, it returns the same instance

Answer (score 0):

basically methods that return "this" are useless - the code that is supposed to call this method already has reference to the object

Comment: That's simply, not true, it is extremely useful for fluent api's.

Comment: Can't edit comments anymore, so: For example: `return new Object().addSubObject(sub1).addReference(ref1).setSomeOptionalThing(thing).calculateSomething()`

Comment: Bas, your code example is correct but is different from the question. In your case the method performs some action and then returns the reference, but his example defines a method that just returns the reference

Comment: I know, I was just responding to your statement 'basically methods that return "this" are useless'

Comment: ok, maybe it sounded too generic, but actually I was refering those kind of methods that just return 'this'

Comment: Fair enough. Well I hope he learned something from my example :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference. Because when you create a `new B()` JVM will allocate a new addres for the object (eg: 100001F), and when you call `new B().get()` it will return the same address (100001F). If you just return `new B()`, it will return the same address (100001F).

My particular opinion: `return new B()` is the best option, because it allocate the object and return the address, instead of allocate and later invoque `get()` method.